# Pausing between image views

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

I want to run a series of pictures with dialog bubble (like a strip cartoon). I've tried to use the action:

```
-(IBAction) runDialog:(id)sender {
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a1.png"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b1.png"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b2.png"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a2.png"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
}
```

This doesn't work. All it does is show the last image (a2.png) After About 20 seconds
Any ideas how I should go about this:showing a series of pictures with a pause in between?

Answer (score 2):

Use NSTimer instead.

```
- (IBAction)runDialog:(id)sender {
    yourInstanceVariableOfNSTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f
        target:self selector:@selector(showNextPage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)showNextPage {
    imageView.image = [yourInstanceVariableOfNSArray 
                            objectAtIndex:++yourInstanceVariableOfNSInteger];
    if (!transitionsFinished) {
        yourInstanceVariableOfNSTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f
            target:self selector:@selector(showNextPage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: I read a comment in an iOS game programming book that timers on iOS get clamped to the interval 1/15 to 1/60 of a second. So longer timers, 5 seconds in your case, should fire every 1/15 of a second. I couldn't find confirmation of this in Apple's docs. Just FYI in case you have a this problem. The 1/60 makes sense because the iOS OpenGL hardware maxes out at 60fps, and won't go faster no matter what you optimize.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to handle this would be to use a UIImageView in the dialog and set its animationImages, animationDuration, etc... properties.